# Correct way of dealing with names of uploaded files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Issue at hand: Following code sometimes throws `System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path`.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
```

Files are uploaded by various end users, so I can't just pretend that this case is invalid and ignore it.

The `UserAgent` string of the failed upload requests usually points at Mac system. And the illegal character (in cases when I bothered to investigate) was some control character in 0-32 range.

The `GetFileName()` call is of course needed because sometimes `HttpPostedFile.FileName` contains just name of the file and sometimes full path on user's machine. I could do something silly like

```
var fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
    fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

but it just doesn't feel right.

Is there no standard "web" way of dealing with uploaded file names? I have hard time accepting I am the first to run into this issue.

==================================================================

To avoid further confusion. The extracted file name is **not** used for storing files on disk and doesn't have to be valid in the context of the hosting environment. It is simply needed to be displayed back to the user.

Comment: I believe the standard way is to generate a file name on the server that doesn't conflict with files uploaded by other users.

Comment: it's not usually a standard but I would say what's more recommended vs what's not.. for example starting names with numbers 1,2,3 ect also keep in mind you should know what things files can handle or not handle in regards to name a file.. I would create a Validation class and check for chars '!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),+,=,{,},[,] you get the idea.. create an arrary of non valid characters or string and only allow "_" or '-' and numbers after the first char... what you have up top is fine but you're only checking for '_' underscore all other naming conventions would go thru

Comment: @dtb The files are stored on disk with names generated by `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")`. Still I need to present user with the original name, which I need to parse somehow.

Comment: you could also format the file name string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("_mmddyyyyhhmmss")) + getting the users domain name to prepend to the file GuIDS work well too but would look rather funny if the user were to have to have access to getting that file

Comment: Why not postfix the guids with the original name? Or store the relation between the GUID and the original name in a database?

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe to just replace characters. You should validate the file name and prompt the user to fix it when not supported (this is perfectly legal, even your OS has limitations on file names).
Otherwise you can:

1. as you said, replace unsupported chars (but how can you ensure you replace ALL the possible invalid chars?)
2. encode the filename

Comment: Doesn't seem like a viable workaround... What am I going to tell them? Please remove character code X from your path name?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the file name as submitted by the user and don't necessarily need a valid file name, you can just strip off any characters up to the last / or \ character:

```
string result = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOfAny(new[] { '/', '\\' }) + 1);
```

<sup>(*LastIndexOfAny* returns -1 if no / or \ is found, so the original string is returned in this case.)</sup>

Don't forget to HTML-encode the file name when showing it to the user.

Answer (score -1):

i normally add DateTime.Now.Ticks to the beginning of a filename, or a user ID (and the ticks), then i can process/move the file based on those details.

Is it possible that the character that is causing the problem is a . (i'm not sure windows deals very well with a . at the beginning of a filename